# Can the charges at the ends of a dipole in a polar molecule exceed unit electronic charge?

Tags: physical-chemistry, dipole

According to my current understanding, charges at the end of the dipole of a polar molecule are formed due to the shifting of the electron cloud towards the more electronegative atom.

In my book it is written "*Ends of dipole possess partial charges. Partial charges are always less than the unit electronic charge $(\pu{1.6x10^-19 C})$*".

Can the charges at the end of the dipole exceed $\pu{1.6x10^-19 C}$ under any condition? (single bond, double bond, triple bond). If not, then why?

Comment: it is 1.6x10^-19 C

Comment: The said charges are not quite a thing that exists, hence they can't be measured accurately.

Comment: The "partial charges" are an notional explanation, not the thing that is observed. What is observed is the strength of the dipole in a molecule. Whether the observed dipole *appears* to need a particular partial charge is the issue.

Comment: You would deal then rather with ionic than covalent bonds.

Comment: "You would deal then rather with ionic than covalent bonds."suppose in a double bond(two electron is shared by each atom) or triple bond(three electrons are shared by each atom), can the electronegative atom pull the shared electron cloud to the extent that the charges at the end of the dipole exceed 1.6×10−19 C.why is that not possible? Is it because the anions are not electronegative to that extent, hence they cannot pull the   electron cloud to the extent that the charges at the end of the dipole exceed 1.6×10−19 C?